# How to programmatically capture packets with high precision timestamps using winpcap?

Tags: timestamp, winpcap

Is there a way doing a live capture with high precision timestamps using winpcap from my c program? High precision is needed for the calculation of jitter and latencies.

Thanks for helping, at least reading till the end of my question..

Comment: Answering as a commend because it is on hold:

Comment: How much precision do you need?

If you are fine with about 0.5-1.5 ms, then:

1. set maximum read timeout `to_ms` to `-1`, as in [WinPcap docs][1]
2. call `timeBeginPeriod(1)` to increase Windows timer precision
3. record time after every call to winpcap as usual

  [1]: http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut3.html

Comment: @Andrew Barber: While this question assumes the reader to be familiar with WinPCap and WinAPI, it is even more specific than, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944790/how-to-allocate-a-memory-to-send-a-large-pcap-file-of-size-larger-than-availabl - definitely not "too broad".

Comment: @wizzard0 Thanks for your reply. Since I am dealing with a kind of real-time Ethernet (100 Mbps) I need a precision < 100 microseconds. I am not sure if this can be achieved using normal HW and a Win OS.

Comment: By "precision" do you mean "resolution", i.e. that if packet A arrives 99 microseconds after packet B, the time stamps differ by 99 microseconds rather than, for example, 0 or 90 100 microseconds, or do you mean "accuracy", i.e. so that if the last octet of packet A arrives on the capturing host's network adapter at 1460704654 seconds, 99 microseconds after midnight, January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, the packet's time stamp is as close to 1460704654 seconds, 99 microseconds as possible?